# Ord function implementation in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Purely as an exercise at home, aimed to better understand some language basics, I tried to reimplement the `Ord` function, but I came across a problem.

In fact, the existing `Ord` function can accept arguments of a variety of different types (`AnsiChar`, `Char`, `WideChar`, `Enumeration`, `Integer`, `Int64`) and can return Integer or Int64.

I can't figure out how to declare multiple versions of the same function.

How should this be coded in Delphi?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Ord` cannot be coded in Delphi. Although you can use [the `overload` directive](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions) to write multiple functions with the same name, you cannot write the `Ord` function that way because it works for an arbitrary number of argument types without needing multiple definitions. (No matter how many `Ord` overloads you write, I can always come up with a type that your functions won't accept but that the compiler's will.)

It works that way because of *compiler magic*. The compiler knows about `Ord` and about all ordinal types in the program, so it performs the function's actions in-line. Other compiler-magic functions include [`Length`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Length) (magic because it accepts arbitrary array types), [`Str`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Str) (magic because it accepts width and precision modifiers), and [`ReadLn`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Readln) (magic because it accepts an arbitrary number of parameters).

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question referenced in the title.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that `ord` would be *impossible* to do in current Delphi by using untyped parameter + some RTTI mess. But granted, at least it would be hugely impractical!

Comment: @Joonas, untyped means there is *no* type. You can't get type information from something that has no type. If you'd suggested using *generics*, then there might be some hope.

Answer (score 12):

> I can't figure out how to declare multiple versions of the same function.

It's called [function overloading](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions). Input parameters must be different for each version, return type doesn't matter. For example:

```
function Ord(X: Char): Integer; overload;
begin
  // Whatever here
end;

function Ord(X: Integer): Integer; overload;
begin
  // Something
end;

// etc.
```

Comment: Although do note that `ord` is a special magic function rather than a normal Pascal function. To drive home that point, recall that `ord` existed long before function overloaded was added to the language.

Comment: True, and if reimplementing for learning purposes, better to call it something else than `ord`!

Comment: As a side note to Davids comment: The implementation of Ord is actually nothing as it produces no extra opcode. It was declared way back in the original Pascal description from N.Wirth and only tells the compiler to ignore the type mismatch. So indeed: bad example...

Comment: You can also side-step the type system by declaring the function with a 'typeless' parameter: `Ord(const Value): Integer` but good luck defining a function that can accept an unknown type and return a meaningful Integer value.

Comment: Uwe is correct. Ord is a compiler primitive that relaxes a particular strong-typed ordinal value to a less-strongly-typed ordinal value, typically from an enum value or character literal, to an Integer or Cardinal.

Comment: +1, since I knew about methods overloading in Delphi, but not about simple functions overloading.